# XSLT Performance Considerations

Tags: java, xml, performance, xslt

I am working on a project which uses following technologies.
Java, XML, XSLs

There's heavy use of XMLs. Quite often I need to 
- convert one XML document into another 
- convert one XML document into another after applying some business logic.

Everything will be built into a EAR and deployed on an application server. As the number of user is huge, I need to take performance into consideration before defining coding standards.

I am not a very big fan of XSLs but I am trying to understand if using XSLs a better option in this scenario or should I stick of Java only. Note that I have requirements to convert XML into XML format only. I don't have requirements to convert XML into some other format like HTML etc.

From performance and manitainability point of view - isnt JAVA a better option than using XLST for XML to XML transformations?

Comment: just to clarify... by XLST you mean a command line tool like xsltproc on most linux systems?

Answer (score 4):

From my previous experience of this kind of application, if you have a performance bottleneck, then it won't be the XSLT processing. (The only exception might be if the processing is very complex and the programmer very inexperienced in XSLT.) There may be performance bottlenecks in XML parsing or serialisation if you are dealing with large documents, but these will apply whatever technology you use for the transformation.

Simple transformations are much simpler to code in XSLT than in Java. Complex transformations are also usually simpler to code in XSLT, unless they make heavy use of functionality available for free in the Java class library (an example might be date parsing). Of course, that's only true for people equally comfortable with coding in both languages.

Of course, it's impossible to give any more than arm-waving advice about performance until you start talking concrete numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with above responses. XSLT is faster and more concise to develop than performing transformations in Java. You can change XSLT without having to recompile the entire application (just re-create EAR and redeploy). Manual transformations should we always faster but the code might be much larger than XSLT due to XPATH and other technologies allowing very condensed and powerful expressions. Try several XSLT engines (java provided, saxon, xalan...) and try to debug and profile the XSLT, using tools like standalone IDE Altova XMLSpy to detect bottleneck. Try to load the XSLT transformation and reuse it when processing several XMLs that require the same transformation. Another option is to compile the XSLT to Java classes, allowing faster parsing (saxon seems to allow it), but changes are not as easy as you need to re-compile XSLT and classes generated.

We use XSLT and XSL-FO to generate invoices for a billing software. We extract the data from database and create an XML file, transform it with XSLT using XSL-FO and process the result XML (FO instructions) to generate a PDF using Apache FOP. When generating invoices of several pages, job is done in less than a second in a multi-user environment and on a user-request basis (online processing). We do also batch processing (billing cycles) and the job is done faster as reusing the XSLT transformation. Only for very-large PDF documents (>100 pages) we have some troubles (minutes) but the most expensive task is always processing XML with FO to PDF, not XML to XML with XSLT.

As always said, if you need more processing power, you can just "add" more processors and do the jobs in parallel easily. I think time saved using XSLT if you have some experience using it can be used to buy more hardware. It's the dichotomy of using powerful development tools to save development time and buy more hardware or do things "manually" in order to get maximum performance.

Integration tools like ESB are heavily based on XSLT transformations to adapt XML data from one system (sender) to another system (receiver) and usually can perform hundreds of "transactions" (data processing and integration) in a second.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a modern XSLT processor, such as Saxon (available in a free version), you will find the performance to be quite good.  Also, in the long term XSL transforms will be much more maintainable than hardcoded Java classes.

(I have no connection with the authors of Saxon)

Answer (score 1):

Here is  my observation based on empirical  data. I use  xslt  extensively ,  and  in many cases  as an  alternative for data processors  implemented in  java. Some  of the data  processors we compiled  are  a bit more  involved.   We  primarily  use  SAXON EE, through the  oxygenxml  editor. Here is what  we  have  noticed in terms of the performance of the transformation.

For less  complex xsl stylesheets, the performance is  quite  good ( 2s  to  read  a 30MB xml file  and  generate 
 over 20 html content pages, with  a lot of  div structures) . and  the  variance  in performance seems about  linear or less   with  respect  to  change  in the size of the  file.

However,  when the  complexity  of  the xsl stylesheet  changes, the performance change can be  exponential.( same file , with a function call introduced  in template  called  often,with the function  implementing  a simple xpath resolution,  can change the processing time , for the same file , from 2s to 24s)  And it seems introduction of  functions  and  function calls  seem to be  a major  culprit. 
That said,  we have not  done  a detailed  performance review and  code  optimization. ( still in alpha  mode, and the  performance is still within our limits - ie batch job  ). I must admit  that we  may have "abused" xsl  function, as in a lot  of places we  used  th idea  of  code abstraction into functions ( in  addition to  using templates ) .  My  suspicion is that,  due t the  nature in which xslt templates are called, there might be  a lot of eventual recursion in the implementation procedures ( for the  xslt  processor), and function calls  can become expensive if they are not  optimized  . We think a  change in "strategy" in way we write our  xsl scripts, (to be more XSLT/XPATH  centric) may help  performance of the  xlst processor. For instance, use  of  xsl keys. so  yes, we maybe just as   guilty as the processor  charged :)

One other  performance issue, is memory  utilization. While  RAM is not technically  a  problem , but a  simple  processor  ramping from  1GB ( !!!  ) to  6GB for a single invocation/transformation is not exactly  kosher. There maybe  scalability and  capacity concerns ( depending on application  and  usage). This may be something less to do  with the underlying xlst processor, and more to do with the  editor tool.This seems to have a  huge impact  on debugging the style sheets in real time ( ie stepping through the xslt ) .

Few observations: 
- commandline  or  "production" invocation of the processor has  better performance 
- for consecutive  runs ( invoking  the xslt processor), the first run takes  the longest ( say  10s) and consecutive runs  take  a lot less ( say 4s ) .Again,  maybe something to  do with the  editor  environment.

That said,  while  performance of the  processors may be  a pain at times ,  and depending on the  application  requirements,  it is  my opinion that if you consider other  factors already  mentioned  here,  such as code maintenance,  ease of  implementation, rapid  changes,  size of  code base, the performance issues may be  mitigated, or  can be  "accepted"  ( if the end application can  still live  with the perfomance numbers ) when comparing implementation using  XSLT  vs Java ( or other )

...adieu!